# NoClassDefFoundError in Teneo tutorial of Peter Friese

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, classnotfound, teneo

I tried out the tene tutorial of peter friese. For those who don't know what im talking about here's a link to it: http://www.peterfriese.de/using-teneo-and-emf-to-store-your-data/

I followed all steps till the end but after that i ran into a no class def found error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/emf/teneo/hibernate/HbMapperException
    at library.main.LibraryDemo.main(LibraryDemo.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.emf.teneo.hibernate.HbMapperException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

I already added the required library as a dependency. So it should be a runtime issue.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: this error generally comes when you miss some jars.Make sure that you have included all the jars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `org.eclipse.emf.teneo.hibernate.mapper.jar` , you can download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgeclipseemfteneohibernatemapperjar.htm)